# Showing LiteDB database items in data grid view

Tags: c#, database, litedb

I'm using LiteDB. Customer definition is like below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Phones { get; set; }
    public string[] Cars { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to show my data in data grid view only first two columns are shown and data grid view doesn't show last two columns which are array.

and this is GetAll

```
private List<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        var issuesToReturn = new List<Customer>();
        try
        {
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(Constants.ConnectionString))
            {
                var issues = db.GetCollection<Customer>("customers");
                foreach (Customer issueItem in issues.FindAll())
                {
                    issuesToReturn.Add(issueItem);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
        return issuesToReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use another field just to format data in you grid (but not stored in datafile). Like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Phones { get; set; }
    public string[] Cars { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string DisplayPhones => string.Join(", ", Phones);

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string DisplayCars => string.Join(", ", Cars);
}
```

Then, change in you grid to map your column using this "Display" properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Include" method to load relative data:

var issues = db.GetCollection("customers").Include(x => x.Phones).Include(x => x.Cars);

Also note that GridView in WPF can't show array in one cell by itself. You need to add columns manually: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. I'm using windows forms

Comment: @HadiBarak I've updated my answer with the link to winforms grid. If it does not work - show how did you try to add that columns